# Are small-size static data good candidates for being defined as Global Variables?

Tags: javascript, express

I have been perusing through the information provided both in stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I have not seen a response that would 100% match to what I have in mind.

Basically, it is about what the title says. I am using *express*. I have sets of data, each of which would roughly have 100-200 rows of objects which in turn have 5-8 fields. While this can naturally be kept in a database collection (I already hold the bigger ones), I am considering to define this data as arrays of objects during runtime, since the data should not take too much memory. Frequency of access would vary; quite often for some of them, and rarely or even none for specific conditions for others.

I know that global variables are bad for a variety of reasons of which I agree to, but this data will be static, never modified, and presumably be more expensive if defined locally and be called every time it is required.

So, even with these conditions of **static** and **low volume**, is it still not recommended to define them once as Global Variables? 
I would then of course redefine those variables locally for those conditions where they will be used multiple times.

If not, please share your view of the alternative.

Comment: In my opinion. The global variables are USUALLY a bad idea. For the scenario you describe I say go for it. Redefining a variable for example in 80 functions from 81 functions is a much worse practice than a global var. Again... this is a personal opinion. I would group that data in a new object, or I would define that data globally if I don't need any further processing with it.

Comment: oh, by redefining I meant, in order to take advantage of the fact that local variables are faster to access than the global

Comment: Are faster to access... but defining them takes time. So... ask yourself these 2 questions. 1. Is it faster to redefine local each time and read from local, or to define once global and read from local. If you read them like 999999999999 times... define local. 2. Does 0.0000001 seconds/access to a var really make a difference? Because if not... your code is cleaner with them global.